# Spacing between UICollectionView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following basic UICollectionView. Now, I am implementing `sizeForItem` by returning size in the following way

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width/3
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: 100.00)
    return size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
```

The view which I get after this is:

[image]

I want the pictures to be equally sized. I dont quite know what am I doing wrong.

How can I solve this?

Size inspector.
[image]

Comment: Using StoryBoard Select UICollectionView remove min spacing default "10"

Comment: @Dix if I'm not mistaking: regardless, if the methods mentioned in the question has been implemented, it doesn't matter what mentioned in the IB.

Comment: please show your UICollectionView "Show the size inspector" menu screen. because  UICollectionView set default  "min spacing" size "10" its set "0".

Comment: Would it make any difference if you implement `collectionView.frame.size.width/3` instead of `collectionView.bounds.size.width/3`?

Comment: Make sure to `reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear` (when the CollectionView is layed out), not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: updates question with `size inspector`.

Comment: @Dix setting the values to zero made the cells split apart at extreme left and right

Comment: Did your try to use autolayout and to put a constraint on your image views by setting up the same width and height and also the aspect ratio ?

Comment: @Arrabidas92 yes! Tried that. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. As @Dix mentioned in the answer to reduce the spacing to zero. Also, to fit all the cells in the grid following should be the width: 
`width - 2`

This way the grid will be aligned to the view and all centered.